# Failed to involve interface method null object reference in my listener and broadcast receiver

Tags: android, connection, broadcastreceiver

Maybe my title of question have some others on stackoverflow, but I can not find any helpful info, so I need anyone help the particular problem of mine:
I want to check Internet connection continuously, so I created a broadcast receiver extends class and it has listener as below:

NetworkStateReceiver.java:

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public interface NetworkStateListener {
        void onNetChange(int status);
    }

    private NetworkStateListener mOnNetworkStateListener;

    public void setNetworkStateListener(NetworkStateListener listener) {
        mOnNetworkStateListener = listener;
    }

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
        if (mOnNetworkStateListener != null)
            mOnNetworkStateListener.onNetChange(status);
    }
}
```

in My Activity:

```
public class FrgChoosing extends Fragment {
    private NetworkStateReceiver mNetworkStateCallback;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        ...
        initNetworkChecking();
    } 
    private void initNetworkChecking() {
        mNetworkStateCallback = new NetworkStateReceiver();
        mNetworkStateCallback.setNetworkStateListener(new NetworkStateListener() {      
            @Override
            public void onNetChange(int status) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (status) {
                case NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI:
                    Functions.toastString("have wifi connection", getActivity());
                    break;
                case NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE:
                    Functions.toastString("have 3g connection", getActivity());
                    break;
                case NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED:
                    Functions.toastString("no connection", getActivity());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
...
<receiver android:name=".NetworkStateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And after see logcat, I believe mOnNetworkStateListener always null when NetworkStateReceiver.onReceiver is triggered.
I don't know where the error? Anyone can help me resolve this problem?
Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Where are you registering your NetworkStateReceiver object to receive broadcasts?

Comment: in initNetworkChecking method at FrgChoosing fragment

Comment: You're instantiating a broadcast receiver, but you haven't registered it yet.  I don't see a call to registerReciever, nor do I see a manifest entry that uses your receiver.

Comment: did you mean the registration in Manifest?, I also edited my question, please see to confirm that.

Comment: @DougStevenson: thank you, i find out solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need Register the broadcast receiver.
Fully FrgChoosing:

```
    private void initNetworkChecking() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!Functions.hasConnection(getActivity())) {
            Functions.toastString(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.alert_no_internet), getActivity());
        }
        mNetworkStateCallback = new NetworkStateReceiver();
        mNetworkStateCallback.setNetworkStateListener(new NetworkStateListener() {      
            @Override
            public void onNetChange(int status) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (status) {
                case NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI:
                    Functions.toastString("co mang wifi", getActivity());
                    break;
                case NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE:
                    Functions.toastString("co mang 3g", getActivity());
                    break;
                case NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED:
                    Functions.toastString("mat mang roi", getActivity());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
        filter.addAction("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED");
        getActivity().registerReceiver(mNetworkStateCallback, filter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

FrgChoosing:

```
    private void initNetworkChecking() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!Functions.hasConnection(getActivity())) {
            Functions.toastString(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.alert_no_internet), getActivity());
        }
        mNetworkStateCallback = new NetworkStateReceiver();
        mNetworkStateCallback.setNetworkStateListener(new NetworkStateListener() {      
            @Override
            public void onNetChange(int status) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (status) {
                case NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI:
                    Functions.toastString("co mang wifi", getActivity());
                    break;
                case NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE:
                    Functions.toastString("co mang 3g", getActivity());
                    break;
                case NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED:
                    Functions.toastString("mat mang roi", getActivity());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

when broadcast is coming, an instance will be created, but It is not the same as the one you created manually. So the listener will be null.

Comment: thanks for your response, can you detail more little...how can i implement the listener?

Comment: broadcast intent will create an instance, you also created an instance, this class now have two examples, but only the listener of what you created is not null. They are independent of each other

Comment: and I suggest you try to use another method to realize your needs, such as broadcast, or show toasts in an another thread.

Comment: What's another method? what broadcast?, sorry about my question, but, can you advise me a example link or code.